# Oauth token_rejected on LinkedIn verification - Intermittent

Tags: django, oauth, linkedin-api, access-token

I'm having problems with Oauth and LinkedIn. Most of the time the verification with Oauth will work fine, but sometimes (something like 1 out of 10 or 20) LinkedIn will return token_rejected.

So far I have checked timestamps to make sure the server is not out of synch (it is not) and that the access-token I send is not malformed (although that should give an error all the time).

I am a bit lost as to where to go from here. I have seen others having intermittent problems with this but no solutions. Does anyone know where to start troubleshooting this?

This is a django app working with apache it that is of any relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: This should now be fixed. Let us know if you still have the problem. Thanks for your patience.

---

I run the LinkedIn Developer Network. Sorry about this. We fixed a bug, but introduced another in the process. :( We're working to fix the new bug. I'll post another comment when the patch is live.

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue. Please fix ASAP. Thanks/

Comment: this is an issue for me on localhost, please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007475/linkedin-ruby-gem-token-rejected-in-callback

Comment: @Adam Trachtenberg We are still facing this issue. Any update lately broke this ? We are running on scribe v1.3.5

Answer (score 1):

Curiously, I faced the same problem a few days ago. Many many users of my website hit the problem for a couple of days, and then all became fine.

What I am going to do is to check if token_rejected is returned, and if so, ask the user of my website to try again after some time.